# Best way to lengthen a section of doorframe?

Tags: door

I’m putting up a stud wall in front of an existing masonry wall that has a door in. I would like to reposition this door on the new stud wall, and this extend/lengthen the middle section of the doorframe for this additional 10cm width.

The existing doorframe is quite ornate though (see photos). I’d rather not throw the whole thing out and start with a new doorframe if possible.

[image]
[image]
[image]

1. Does anyone recognise which router bits I’d need to create new inner profiles?
2. What is the best way to cut the blue frame away from the middle section to allow for extension and reattachment later on?

Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: it looks to me like the blue part should just need a pri-bar to remove it, normally something like that is just nailed on, though it is possible it might have been glued.  either way, removing it is the same. just be careful.  and if it was nailed, either pull the nails through the back or clip them off to save the face.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. These are two completely different queries and each should have its own Question. Please edit this one down to just your 1, clarifying exactly what you mean by "inner profile".

Comment: But re. your 2, on something with this complex a moulding the chances of you successfully routing new sections and scarfing them in to lengthen are, I suspect, about zero. Even an expert with an extensive bit collection might find it challenging to get something that was visually close enough it could be used adjacent, but to actually insert into a run of the old moulding is something else entirely. That requires basically a *perfect* recreation. So I think actually the best approach might be a non-woodworking one, and that's to make a mould and cast it (after stripping back to bare wood).

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers. I think I'll try to find the joints where the moulding is attached / slotted into the door jamb part, and prize them apart carefully. I'll keep the cornices and try to create a new door jamb in the style of the old one for the new length. I completely agree with @Graphus that mimicking the original is nearly impossible to do well.